# Dedicated Router for VR gaming setup

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, wireless-router, virtual-desktop

I bought a RT-AX55 router to use as an offline, dedicated router for VR gaming on the Oculus Quest 2. I play Skyrim VR, so it does not need to be connected to the internet. Currently I have it in access point mode using Virtual Desktop, however i've been looking into static IPs, changing DNS to cloudflare/google, etc. In game I have encoding/decoding speeds ranging from 7-20ish ms depending. I'd like to keep them as low as possible.

What settings would be best to get the lowest latency from a dedicated router?

Comment: upstream DNS is meaningless if you arent; connected to the internet. no idea what you mean by virtual desktop in conjunction with a wifi router in AP mode. those things don't seem related. static IPs won;t change anything from a performance perspective, and it may (or may not, no idea) be difficult to set a private IP on an interface-less device like your VR headset. nothing you are talking about will have an impact on performance.